# mapply not having same return datatype

Tags: r, mapply

It return string once and integer other time

```
f <- function(a){
  if (a > 10) 
    return("any string")
  else
    return(a)
}

mapply(f,c(1,20,10))
[1] "1" "any string" "any string"
```

but I want the return value of the function in original form as first is integer

```
[1] 1 "any string" "any string"
```

Comment: You cannot have mixed data type in a vector. Try lists.

Comment: Still having same issue

Comment: Try `Map` instead of `mapply`

Comment: In this case `lapply` will do just fine, there's no need to complicate when the function only has one argument. `f<-function(a){if(a>10){"any string"}else{a}};lapply(c(1,20,10),f)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your example is not working? `vector` in R could contains only one data type. When a few types is provided automatic conversion is applied always to lower level representation - here to a character. A `list` have to be used to grab different data types.
Solution with Map

```
f <- function(a){
if(a>10)
return('any string')
else{
return(a)
}
}

Map(f, c(1,20,10))
```